# Adding shadow to layer causes degraded retina appearance

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, calayer

I've got a problem with CALayer shadows.  Here's how I'm making my view:

```
UIImage *screenshot = [SomeClass getScreenshot:mainView.view]; //full screen snap
CGFloat scale = [SomeClass getScreenScale]; // 1 or 2 for retina
CGFloat width = mainView.view.frame.size.width;
CGRect r1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, width*scale, 300*scale);     
CGRect u1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 300);
CGImageRef ref1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], r1);
l1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:u1];
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref1];
[l1 setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[l1 setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
CGImageRelease(ref1);
[mainView.view addSubview:l1];
```

Okay, so that works just fine.  The image added is retina resolution. However, as soon as I add a shadow to the layer it jumps to standard resolution, making the button appear fuzzy.

```
l1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
l1.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
l1.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
l1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
l1.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Is there any reason why adding a shadow would cause this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I cannot really tell, why it happens, but I assume it is caused by the UIImage creation. You created a large(retina size 600 * 600 pixels) CGImageRef and from that the UIImage. But the UIImage is not aware, that it is a retina image (it now has 600 * 600 points, it should have 300 * 300 points with scale factor 2 which again will result in 600 * 600 pixels).

Please try to create your `UIImage` using `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:`. This will make the UIImage aware of retina-scale and the layer operations may work out ok.

So your line would be:

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref1 
    scale: scale 
    orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

**Edit** (see my comment below): The issue is caused by `l1.layer.shouldRasterize = YES`. You need to specify `l1.layer.rasterizationScale = scale` as well and the image renders as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work.  Still reverts to standard resolution. :/

Comment: I tried it out myself. The cause is for the bad rendering is the l1.layer.shouldRasterize = YES; You need to set l1.layer.rasterizationScale = scale as well.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks for helping!